# Sending an array of objects as ajax post data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My overall goal is to get all some of all drop-downs on a page and send that to be processed by a php file.

Right now, the way I'm doing it in jQuery is making an overall schedule array and then adding each element to be updated to that array. So I have something like:

```
var schedule = [];
var data = { 
   'user_id' : '12', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Monday',
    'when' : 'start',
    'time' : '12 AM'
 }
schedule.push(data);
var data = { 
   'user_id' : '13', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Tuesday',
    'when' : 'end',
    'time' : '12 AM'
 }
schedule.push(data);
// schedule would have two objects in it
```

Obviously in loops and and stuff.

So, my schedule array has two objects in it, in this case.

Now, is it possible to use that schedule array as the ajax data? It doesn't work if I do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://something.com/ajax',
  data: schedule,
  type: 'POST'
});
```

But if I instead change it to `schedule[0]` it works just fine, but only for the first thing in the schedule array, obviously.

Comment: Remove the ' '..schedule is a variable, not a string. Also jQuery will encode your array as a JSON object you'll need to decode on the server.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Schedule isn't an array of arrays. It is an array of objects, as `data` is an object.

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using `type: 'JSON'`?

Comment: @xbonez: You are correct. Does that change anything in this case?

Comment: @Truth: No specific reason besides the fact that I'm very new at ajax.

Comment: @Ben: Probably not. I was just confused whether I had the concept of objects in JS wrong.

Comment: What happens when you print_r($_POST) in your php script?

Comment: I get `Array ( [schedule] => [object Object] )`. If I do a `print_r($_POST['schedule'])` I get `[object Object]`

Comment: Despite all the suggestions and help, I still cannot get any data to my php script. Using `data: {schedule: schedule}`, if I say `print_r($_POST)` I get `Array ( [schedule] => [object Object] )` which seems okay. If I then say `print_r($_POST['schedule'])` I get `[object Object]` which I can't seem to do anything with. Doing a `var_dump($_POST['schedule'])` it tells tells me `string '[object Object]' (length=15)`. Is there something I need to do to convert the string object to a real object?  It doesn't make much sense to me :/

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle of your code? I'll take a look.

Comment: @Chris hopefully I did this right: http://jsfiddle.net/AyjcP/

Comment: That code is just fine. You don't need the parenthesis around the data object, that isn't hurting anything though. Are you using Firebug? Take a look at the post data -- all is in order. Now let's look at your PHP. Use http://codepad.org, make sure to choose PHP language on the left.

Comment: Using codeigniter so the URL is `site_url('admin/update_schedule')`. That update_schedule function, at the moment, only has `var_dump($_POST['schedule']);` in it. I did compare the post data in my setting versus the jsfiddle data and it was different. Jsfiddle data looked correct but mine was just `schedule [object Object]` over and over.

Comment: Interesting... what precise version of jQuery do you have there?

Comment: Oh good lord, I'm going to go cry in a corner. Some how the 7 in 1.7.2 got removed so it was just grabbing 1.2 from Google :/. Works now! Time to stop working on this for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct version of jQuery. In earlier versions, you had to pass a sting; new versions use "intelligent guess" on the `data` variable. You can either explicitly tell jQuery that you're passing it a javascript object with the `dataType` parameter, or you can let jQuery figure it out.

**Documentation**

`jQuery.ajax()` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 11):

The `data` attribute should be an object.

What you can do is this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://something.com/ajax',
  data: {schedule: schedule},
  type: 'POST'
});
```

So if you receive this for example in PHP you have `$_POST["schedule"]`. An that is exactly the same as you had in JavaScript.

Ohh yes I've forgot... also have a look at [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)!

Comment: The current jQuery docs states it can be an object, string or an array.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://something.com/ajax',
  data: {schedule: schedule},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

It would send a JSON encoded string to the server, which server-side languages can parse. (in PHP, it's done with `json_decode()`).

Comment: What am I passing to json_deocde() though? $_POST['schedule'] ?

Comment: @Ben: Yes. `schedule` will consist of the the JSON string.

Comment: Either way, I keep getting nothing. I've tried doing `type: 'POST'` and `type: 'JSON'` with either combination of data and I keep getting a null value. What might be wrong? If I do a `console.log(schedule)` before the ajax part, I can see all my objects so I know they're there.

Comment: do you know the alternative of function `json_decode()` for python??